# How does OneNote differ between "View Notebooks" and "View Notebooks in Your Org"?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I'm creating an application to work with OneNote in Office 365 and so I'm creating an app registration in Azure.  I want to be able to view notebooks, and there are two permission options:  View notebooks and View notebooks in your organization.  Irrespective of which permission I select, the only notebooks the call returns are ones in the currently authenticated user's personal site (using "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/notebooks" as the Url for the GET request).

So...is it because of the Url I'm using (I haven't found any documentation that uses anything other than ".../me/..."), or is it just working as expected?  For example, there's no documentation I've found that describes what all notebooks "in your organization" means - does that include every SharePoint site collection Notebook?  Something else?  Any additional details or links to specific information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to Get Personal Notebooks in the Users OneDrive For Business (/me/) as well as Notebooks hosted in SharePoint sites(/myorganization/) that the user has access to.

**Organization Notebooks** - 
https://www.onenote.com/api/{version}/myorganization/siteCollections/{id}/sites/{id}/notes/notebooks

You would need **SiteCollectionId** and **SiteId** to access the organization notebooks.

To understand how you get the notebooks (in the users organization) by referring to this documentation - 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2015/06/11/and-sharepoint-makes-three/

Answer (score 0):

I did finally find the documentation where they list the different locations from which you can request notebooks: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-get-content.  Also, to get the gist of my question, although the service uses a common Url to access notebooks, there isn't a single location where you can ask for all notebooks in an organization.  The Azure permission merely gives you the right to go get them if you can find them.  As noted in the first answer above, if you know where they are at and if you have the right permissions with your app then that all works great.  But you have to know where they are, because there doesn't seem to be a discovery type API for them.